# hapi fhir elastic search how to configure

Tags: elasticsearch, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I am using hapi fhir v5.1.0 with jpa server(`hapi-fhir-jpa-server-starter`). As per the description, this version contains elastic search library for text search.

How can I configure elastic server here?

I see some entries in the `properties` file and configured the elastic rest url, but nothing works and always get the following error - `HSEARCH000222 - the search factory was not initialized`.

Could someone please let me know the configuration steps required to activate elastic search inside hapi fhir jpa server?