# Has the FHIR v5.0 specification been released?

Tags: hl7-fhir, fhir-server-for-azure

I am trying to find the FHIR 5.0 specifications and saw that some [people seem to be using the FHIR v5.0 server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64282487/14607026) already. According to the [official FHIR blog](https://onfhir.hl7.org/2019/01/20/fhir-r5-roadmap/), the specification was supposed to be released in the 3rd quarter of this year (of course COVID could have slowed this down). Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5.0 is in development and is scheduled to start balloting in May 2021.  It's not likely to publish as a final 'official' release until Q2 2022.  However, there's a "continuous integration build" that shows what the current proposed content for R5 is hosted here: http://build.fhir.org.  As well, we produce snapshots of the draft R5 release for connectathons and other purposes so that there's a semi-stable release people can write code against when testing for connectathon.

The current timeline has indeed been impacted by COVID, but it's also been impacted by the appetite of the community for a new release and the ever increasing amount of work involved in producing a new release.

Comment: Note: The times quoted above reflect 'current plans' - they are not firm and will be influenced by the results of the balloting process as well as feedback from designers and implementers.

Answer (score 0):

On 2023-03-26, R5 has being released !!

http://hl7.org/fhir/directory.html